# Gulp: Run code after asynchronous tasks have completed

Tags: gulp

I have a Gulp task with the following mission: Get a list of folders. Count the words in the folder. Report the count for each folder and a grand total count.

So far, this is what I have.

```
gulp.task('count', function() {

  ['folder1','folder2',...].forEach(function(folderName) {
    gulp.src(['./'+folderName+'/**/*.md']).pipe(countWords(folderName));
  });

});
```

After all of the folders' words have been counted, I want to call a function `reportGrandTotal`. I have spent hours trying to figure out how to do this. The problem is that the `gulp.src().pipe()` chain runs asynchronously. In many of the patterns I have tried, `reportGrandTotal` ends up running before any of the `gulp.src().pipe()` chains complete.

How do I modify this task so that, once all of the `gulp.src().pipe()` chains have completed, I can run `reportGrandTotal` and get the grand total?

Comment: Use the [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence)

Comment: Using `run-sequence` doesn't work. Gulp starts the aggregations, completes the task, then starts and completes the grand total task--before it completes the aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question, you can specify a dependency for reportGrandTotal, make sure that all your tasks use a callback or return a stream or a promise.

```
gulp.task('reportGrandTotal', ['count'], function(){
    // your code
}
```

the second parameter will be a dependency and reportGrantTotal should not run before the dependency is done. [Gulp docs for dependencies](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#deps)

Comment: Doesn't work. Gulp starts the aggregations, completes the task, then starts and completes the grand total task--before it completes the aggregations.